# Why does img[0:overlap,:,:] = 1 work but in numpy but not img = img[0:overlap,:,:] = 1 does not?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I created an array of zeroes in numpy:

```
img = np.zeros((30, 30, 3), np.uint8)
```

I'd like to set a certain amount to 1s by using an overlap variable.  That overlap tells me how many columns  in I want the 1s to start.  When I try doing it this way

```
img = img[0:overlap,:,:] = 1
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

But when I do this it's fine:

```
 img[0:overlap,:,:] = 1
```

Am I thinking incorrectly about these array objects?  Why can't i just reset the array the first was by assigning it back to the same array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, this is a tricky one.

When you do this:

```
x = y = 42
```

You're assigning the value 42 to both `x` and `y`. But, in practice, `x` is assigned its value first and then `y` is assigned the same value. So, it's shorthand for:

```
x = 42
y = 42
```

Now, look at your code:

```
img = img[0:overlap,:,:] = 1
```

This is shorthand for:

```
img = 1
img[0:overlap,:,:] = 1
```

And of course you'll agree that `1[0:overlap,:,:]` makes no sense and correctly throws a `TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`.

By the way, `img[0:overlap, :, :] = 1` already modifies `img`, why are you trying the assignment? I.e.:

```
import numpy as np

overlap = 2
img = np.zeros((3, 4, 2), np.uint8)
img[0:overlap, :, :] = 1
print(img)
```

Result:

```
[[[1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]]

 [[1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]]

 [[0 0]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]]]
```

Comment: Well the "By the way" comment was what I was trying to understand :).  I guess I didn't completely understand how the matrices were treated in numpy.  I think this makes sense - thank you!